# Installing Laravel with a database on another system

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, configuration

We have a local network, in the server's system I install SQL Server 2017, now I must install Laravel in my system with the server's database but I got this error

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].

my config

```
SQL Host : DESKTOP-Q03NUTO\LS
SQL Port : 1707
SQL Login: sa
SQL Password: ***
```

Comment: Where did you stored this config?

Comment: did you change the database driver MySQL to sqlsrv?

Comment: @SKG hi, yes change driver to sqlsrv